# What's google's position on programmatically querying pagerank?

Tags: pagerank

Is there a public API for programmatically querying pagerank?  If so, for what level of volumes would it be permitted for a service to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from google guideline page 
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769

> "Don't use unauthorized computer
>   programs to submit pages, check
>   rankings, etc. Such programs consume
>   computing resources and violate our
>   Terms of Service. Google does not
>   recommend the use of products such as
>   WebPosition Gold™ that send automatic
>   or programmatic queries to Google"

So I guess that is a no.

But I found this: http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/PageRank/ that you could try. I do not know if it is "legal".

Answer (score 3):

From my Experience, It's OK to query page-rank as long as you do it with 1 second intervals, otherwise Google blocks you IP address after a few queries. if you're using .net there is library to help query page-rank anagrammatically , you can [find it here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Google_Pagerank.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just tried a PageRank tool, and the answer from Google is clear :

http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?&answer=86640&hl=en

That says :

> "If you tried the steps above and haven't resolved the issue, it's very likely that a user or a computer in your network is sending automated traffic to Google. Your network administrator may be able to locate and shut down the source of the automated traffic; feel free to refer them to this page. Sending automated queries of any sort to Google is against our Terms of Service. This includes, among other things, the following activities:
>
> - Using any software that sends queries to Google to determine how a website or webpage ranks on Google for various queries"

So the answer is NO : Google forbids and blocks those kind of queries !